# JTable listener problem

Tags: java, swing, mouse, jtable, listener

I added a mouse clicked listner to my jtable, when i double click the row, will pop up an window accordingly.

```
jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
double amount = Double.parseDouble(jTable.getValueAt(getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
String remarks = jTable.getValueAt(getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();
String transactionID = jTable.getValueAt(getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
        new EditFrame(...)
}
});
```

This code I used to retrieve the row selected row.

```
public int getSelectedRow() {
jTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
new ListSelectionListener() {
 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
  int viewRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
  selectedRow = viewRow;
  System.out.println(viewRow);
 }
});
return selectedRow;
}
```

In my case, I realised when I clicked the second row in the first time, I get null for selectedRow, only when I select first row then second row, I then can get the correct data. And If I removed the mouse listener the problem then be solved. Is it because I doing something wrong at the mouse click listener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know what row was clicked then you don't need the selection listener. Just use:

```
table.rowAtPoint();
```

Answer (score -1):

You're doing it the wrong way. Remove your current `getSelectedRow()` method completely and never try to code something similar. Here is a better version:

```
jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
int selectedRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
double amount = Double.parseDouble(jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 4).toString());
String remarks = jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 3).toString();
String transactionID = jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1).toString();
        new EditFrame(...)
}
});
```